# iw fails to configure interface

Tags: linux, wifi

I have two PCs:

- Ubuntu 12.04.4, 3.5.0-45-generic (let's call it "myGoodPC")
- Ubuntu 12.04.3, 3.8.0-35-generic (let's call it "myBadPC")

`myBadPC` operates in a virtual machine of ESXi 5.0.0.

In `myGoodPC` I manage to configure the wireless interface properly:

```
root@myGoodPC:~# sudo iw --debug dev wlan0 set channel 10 HT40-
-- Debug: Sent Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 44
    .nlmsg_type = 24 <0x18>
    .nlmsg_flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398703424
    .nlmsg_pid = 14796
  [PAYLOAD] 28 octets
    02 00 00 00 08 00 03 00 08 00 00 00 08 00 26 00 99 09 ..............&...
    00 00 08 00 27 00 02 00 00 00                         ....'.....
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
-- Debug: Received Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 36
    .nlmsg_type = 2 <ERROR>
    .nlmsg_flags = 0 <>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398703424
    .nlmsg_pid = 14796
  [ERRORMSG] 20 octets
    .error = 0 "Success"
  [ORIGINAL MESSAGE] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 16
    .nlmsg_type = 24 <0x18>
    .nlmsg_flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398703424
    .nlmsg_pid = 14796
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
```

Also I successfully sniff WiFi data packets (ICMP / ping packets).

In `myBadPC` an error appears when trying to configure:

```
root@myBadPC:~# sudo iw --debug dev wlan0 set channel 10 HT40-
-- Debug: Sent Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 44
    .nlmsg_type = 25 <0x19>
    .nlmsg_flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398698982
    .nlmsg_pid = 14533
  [PAYLOAD] 28 octets
    02 00 00 00 08 00 03 00 03 00 00 00 08 00 26 00 99 09 ..............&...
    00 00 08 00 27 00 02 00 00 00                         ....'.....
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
-- Debug: Received Message:
--------------------------   BEGIN NETLINK MESSAGE ---------------------------
  [HEADER] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 64
    .nlmsg_type = 2 <ERROR>
    .nlmsg_flags = 0 <>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398698982
    .nlmsg_pid = 14533
  [ERRORMSG] 20 octets
    .error = -16 "Device or resource busy"
  [ORIGINAL MESSAGE] 16 octets
    .nlmsg_len = 16
    .nlmsg_type = 25 <0x19>
    .nlmsg_flags = 5 <REQUEST,ACK>
    .nlmsg_seq = 1398698982
    .nlmsg_pid = 14533
---------------------------  END NETLINK MESSAGE   ---------------------------
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

Obviously I fail to sniff data packets (ICMP/ping) after this command (but broadcast are visible).

Note: I removed other commands from the above code for clarity (like `ifconfig wlan0 down` that comes before `iw` or `iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor` and `ifconfig wlan0 up` that come after).

What could make wlan0 to have errors in `myBadPC`?

Comment: Isn´t this wireless card already in use by your hypervisor?

Comment: That "wireless card" is a D-Link DWA-160 (rev.A2) USB stick, which is associated with `myBadPC`. If I can read from it (since it's "belong" to `myBadPC`) - so I should be able to modify it.. right?

Comment: It depends on how supported is this device to the feature "Usb Passthrough" on ESXi. I suggest you to take a look at this page: http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=io - Get the USB ids using `lsusb` and check if this model of network adapter is compatible ;)

Other option is that you will need to instal vmware-tools on this machine(not openvtools)

Comment: The output for `lsusb` is: `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 07d1:3a09 D-Link System DWA-160 802.11abgn Xtreme N Dual Band Adapter(rev.A2) [Atheros AR9170+AR9104]`. I don't find the USB ids (`07d1:3a09`) in any of the drop-down lists which on that page. Does it mean that this device isn't supported at all by VMWare?

Comment: It is not supported at all, but navigating inside vmware forums you can see some people getting USB wireless chips working(`DWA-140` is one of them). Is this wireless allocated to other virtual machine too? If you have multiple vm´s running you could see if this hardware is shown to them, and delete to avoid that there is any chance that other machine already allocated this.